# PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() returns null

Tags: java, printing, applet

`PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()` returns `NULL` as I have a printer installed and set to default printer.

If I am using this in a simple program it works fine, but when I try to use it in my applet-based program it returns `NULL`.

Please send me some good solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you considered using JNLP? If not what happens when you use PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the printer (or any resource on the host computer for that matter) the jar file in which the applet code resides has to be signed, and the user must accept the signer as a trusted party.
To sign the jar file, use the jarsigner program, which is part of he JDK. Jarsigner uses its own keystore, so if you have your own certificate, you must import the certificate to a keystore first. It can generate certificates as well, in the case you don't have any other certificate to sign the jar file with.

[Documentation of the jarsigner tool can be found here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html)

Note that newer Java runtimes do ask the user if (s)he allows the code to access the printer, but I found that regardless of the answer, code in an unsigned jar file is prevented from accessing resources.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working in an signed applet in windows with 1.7.0_55:

```
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;

...

HashDocAttributeSet docAttr=new HashDocAttributeSet();
HashPrintRequestAttributeSet reqAttr=new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

try {
    PrintService pserv = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    if (pserv == null) {
        System.out.println("ERROR-01: no default print service");
    }
    System.out.println("Printer: " + pserv.getName());

    DocPrintJob job = pserv.createPrintJob();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    String content = makeZplLabel();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(content.getBytes(), flavor, docAttr);

    job.print(doc, reqAttr);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR-02:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change the security settings for java applets first. By default, java applets cannot print.

Comment: i have changed the settings and also printing using the Printable Interface, but now i have to use PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() it returns null to me.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  The PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrinterService() returns null.  Please let me know if you resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that printer.conf defines `<DefaultPrinter name>` instead of `<Printer name>`. JVM seems to only find a default printer that is defined like this.

This code snippet could help out to quickly verify if it works:

```
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

public class checkDefaultPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, make sure the Print Spooler service is running. Also, You can test this code while applying the solution

```
import javax.print.PrintService; 
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup; 

public class JavaPrintBug { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // returns an empty array unless a user has opened system printer settings 
        // only short time ago or an adminstrator has set cupsctl WebInterface=yes 
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null); 
        System.out.println("Number of printers available: " + printServices.length); // zero 
         
         
        // returns null unless a user has opened system printer settings only 
        // short time ago or an adminstrator has set cupsctl WebInterface=yes 
        PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
        if(null != defaultPrintService) { // will not be entered 
            System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrintService.getName()); 
        } 
         
        // before entering this loop make sure that NO user has opened system 
        // printer settings only short time ago and NO administrator has set 
        // cupsctl WebInterface=yes (hWebInterface=no)! 
        while(null == PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService()) { 
            // while trapped in here, open system printer settings or set 
            // cupsctl WebInterface=yes and the loop will be left. 
            // In Windows, enable the Print Spooler service
        } 
        System.out.println("Workaround worked!"); 
    } 
}
```

Reference: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8178715