# PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() always returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, printing

PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() always returns null.

There's a printer installed, it works...

```
lpstat -d
```

returns

```
system default destination: Canon-MP560-2
```

Also,

```
uname -a
```

returns

```
... 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Writing everything in Eclipse:  Luna Release (4.4.0).  Not a lot of customization going on there beyond an installation of Jasper Reports and its myriad dependencies.  Also installed window-builder and that's it.  Everything is pretty out-of-the-box.  Printer is a network printer, but again... LibreOffice has no difficulty printing to it.  I'm wildly perplexed.

Watching things in the debugger, this always comes back null.

```
PrintService[] services  = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
PrintService myPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

In both cases, services == myPrinter == null.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Interesting comments in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html#getDefaultPrintService()), *"Not called directly by applications. Implemented by a service provider, and called by the print lookup service"* and *"Returns: the default PrintService for this lookup service. If there is no default, returns null."*. There's a difference between the "default printer" and what the `PrintServiceLookup` is using as it's designated printer

Comment: How does one configure a default print 'service'?  By the read of the JavaDoc, this implies that configuring a default printer is somehow a different process than configuring a default print service.  Where does one go to configure a print service (that is not the same as configuring a printer but would be useful for this application).

Comment: What OS are you using?  Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to configure your own service, that's kind of the point...

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS... could this be an Eclipse issue?  Perhaps some kind of security 'feature'?  I've heard of applet's not being able to print by default, but never a Java application as this is intended to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

If you just uncompress eclipse and run it in your home directory... it seems as if things that you compile in Java won't be able to play well with the operating system.  Reason for doing a 'local' install like this was because Ubuntu's default config when you do a "sudo apt-get install eclipse" is to give you version 3.8.  For some very specific reasons, I needed the current version, which is 4.4.

To fix this, I did an apt-get install of eclipse, and then uncompressed (as root) the eclipse archive over /usr/lib/eclipse.  Finally, build a symbol link between /usr/bin/eclipse to /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse and then commence cleanup (re-installation of missing pacakges, etc).  Once this was all done, the application I compiled was able to dump a job in to the print queue.

Of course, it's entirely possible that the act of re-installing caused some other mess I had created to be fixed.  If anyone else has this problem, and their copy of eclipse was installed the same way, then it might be something worth trying.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer for this question in general.

Answer (score 3):

Check out answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492176/1995068. Turns out PrintServiceLookup can only find default printers which are defined as `<DefaultPrinter>` in printer.conf of CUPS. When adding a default printer through cups command line, its being defined as `<Printer>` which doesn't seems to do it for PrintServiceLookup

Comment: Thank you - a million % thank you.  We had our IT guys do an upgrade and as part of it they ported over the existing and old printers.conf file which wiped out the <default> which apparently is necessary!!!